# Select a row if it meets first condition and discard following conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, select

this is what I want to achieve:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM  ventas WHERE (
posicion = 'cc21' 
AND inic < NOW() 
AND fin > NOW()
) ELSE (
WHERE posicion = 'cc21' 
AND fijo = 1)
ELSE ( WHERE posicion = 'cc21' 
AND hits < limite ) 
AND contenido = 'notas' 
LIMIT 1
```

I've tried JOIN and other examples in this site but non seems to point me on the right direction for this particular case, Any help is appreciated :)

This dindn't work

```
    SELECT 
      TOP (1) * 
    FROM
      ventas 
    WHERE posicion = 'cc21' 
      AND (inic < NOW() AND fin > NOW()) 
      OR (fijo = 1) 
      OR (hits < limite) 
      AND contenido = 'notas' 
    LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that directly using `OR`

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    ventas 
WHERE   
        (
            (posicion = 'cc21' AND inic < NOW() AND fin > NOW())
            OR
            (posicion = 'cc21' AND fijo = 1)
            OR
            (posicion = 'cc21' AND hits < limite ) 
        )
        AND 
        contenido = 'notas' 
LIMIT   1
```

Comment: I tried that but if a previous row meets the second condition than I don't get the one I want

Comment: can you give sample records with desired result?

Comment: what is the result if you execute the query? define *..I don't get what I want*

Comment: OK I have two banners, and I want to display one where the hits are less than the targeted limit, that I can do whit no problem, but what if I have a banner that must be automatically inserted and temporarily substitute the one with the hits for just a given period of time...

Comment: Right I'm using MySQL, TOP doesn't work... You see using your code witch I already tried it gives me the last condition. And what I want is the first condition to take effect first and discard the rest automatically

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the TOP clause to get the first row.

As to the rest of your query, it is really confusing for me to understand. However, you need to use AND and OR operators to make this work. You can group them using parentheses (brackets).

SELECT TOP (1) * FROM ventas
WHERE posicion = 'cc21' AND ( (A AND B) OR (C) OR (D))

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after diving and not finding fish I resorted to this:

```
$cc21 = mysqli_query($not,"SELECT * FROM ventas WHERE posicion = 'cc21'
AND inic < NOW() AND fin > NOW() and contenido = 'notas' LIMIT 1");
if (mysqli_num_rows($cc21) == 0) {
$cc21 = mysqli_query($not,"SELECT * FROM ventas WHERE posicion = 'cc21'
AND fijo = '1' and contenido = 'notas' LIMIT 1");
if (mysqli_num_rows($cc21) == 0) {
$cc21 = mysqli_query($not,"SELECT * FROM ventas WHERE posicion = 'cc21' AND hits < limite AND  contenido = 'notas' LIMIT 1");
}
}
```

It's not clean nor compact but it gets the job done ;)

Tank you all for your invaluable help